# What are the differences between jquery-rails and rails-assets-jquery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Generally I used the `jquery-rails` gem to embed `jQuery` into my `rails` projects. Now I started to use [rails-assets](https://rails-assets.org/) and some of the gems have depend on `rails-assets-jquery`, which also provides `jquery`.

My question is, can I just remove `jquery-rails`? Is there something special about `jquery-rails` or another reason to keep it in my project?

My gem file (shortened version) looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
source 'https://rails-assets.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.5'

#gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.1.2' # jQuery
gem 'rails-assets-jquery'
gem 'rails-assets-slick-carousel'
```

Comment: I can't find the rails-assets-jquery, please show your  Gemfile

Comment: I've added my gem file.

Comment: ahha, rails-assets.org

Comment: It seems that yes, the `rails-assets-jquery` covers `jquery-rails`, but probably you need to port helper from the second gem to first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is, the `rails-assets-WHATEVER` is a package from [Bower.io](http://bower.io/) while the other one is from [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org). So, in a ideal world there's no difference between `rails-assets-jquery` and `jquery-rails`. So, you have to assume that the authors are pushing new versions at the same time to both repositories: Bower and RubyGems. However, in real world there are different maintainers of packages and the numbering of versions does not always match. [Rails Assets project](https://rails-assets.org/) tries to unify packaging systems (of Ruby and JavaScript projects) into a single file (Gemfile).

Anyway, the recommended usage is:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.1.5'
#gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.1.2' # jQuery

source 'https://rails-assets.org' do 
  gem 'rails-assets-jquery'
  gem 'rails-assets-slick-carousel'
end
```

just to make clear, that your not downloading `rails-assets-jquery` from [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org), in fact someone might have uploaded such a package to [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org).